# how to set View encapsulation globally on angular universal or SSR

Tags: css, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

How to set globally ViewEncapsulation.None on angular universal or angular ssr?

Our app is running on Angular 8 as server-side render, however, we have over 200 components and to apply view encapsulation to all seems a lot of work. We use to have the app as aot but now we are moving to angular as ssr

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,[
        {
            defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
            preserveWhitespaces: false,
        }
      ]).then(() => {
      }).catch(err => console.error(err));
    });
```

However, when the page render on express.js seems not working.
Any ideas?